# Can't upgrade Magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

**Hi Stackoverflow**

Im having problem updating Magento 2.1.6 to 2.2.1 because our theme requires that version atleast. When i try to update by SSH i get the follow error:

[image: Cant update magento 2 til 2.2.1]

As seen above it return an error. Ive been looking everywhere and i cant seem to figure out what the problem could be?

Below you see some of my composer.json where i tried to input the needed infomrations for the update.

```
"name": "magento/magento2ce",
"description": "Magento 2 (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.2.1",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.1",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha"
},
```

Hope you guys can help :)

Comment: Please post you `repositories` node from you composer.json file. It needs to include the `repo.magento.com` link there so composer knows where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Step A: Access Your Server using SSH

Step B: Navigate to the Magento 2 Root directory

Step C: Upgrade Commands

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 --no-update
Then execute this all commands

composer update

rm -rf generated

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex